# jQuery animate() is not working properly on margin-left when used in scrollTop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a span class which should be shown using the animate() when user scrolls down to 160px;
It is working properly for first and second time, after that animate() is showing very slowly.

My code is..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head lang="en">
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>tokka</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <style>
                /*-------------- TopBar----------*/
                #topbar{
                    padding: 0px;
                    background-color: #2483A0;
                }
                #topbar .topextra{
                    background-color: #000000;
                    color: #ffffff;
                }

                #topbar .collection .logo_box{
                    min-width: 200px;
                    padding: 1px;
                }
                #topbar .collection .logo_box a{
                    display: inline-block;
                    margin-right: 5px;
                    color: #ffffff;
                }

            </style>
            <script language="javascript" src="../lib/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
            <script language="JavaScript" src="../lib/bootstrap/bootstrap.js"></script>

            <script language="JavaScript" src="../lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
            <script language="javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $(function () {
                        $(window).scroll(function () {
                            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 160) {
                                $("#category_navbar").slideUp(function(){
                                    $(".topextra").slideUp();
                                    $("#showmenow").animate({'margin-left':"0px"});
                                });
                            } else {
                                $(".topextra").slideDown(function(){
                                    $("#category_navbar").fadeIn();
                                    $("#showmenow").animate({'margin-left':"-50px"});
                                });
                            }
                        });

                        // scroll body to 0px on click
                        /*$('#back-top a').click(function () {
                            $('body,html').animate({
                                scrollTop: 0
                            }, 600);
                            return false;
                        });*/
                    });
                });
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <br><br><br><br>
            <div id="topbar" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top topnavbar no-radius" role="navigation">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row topextra">
                        something
                    </div>
                    <div class="row collection">
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <div class="navbar-header">
                                <div class="logo_box pull-right">
                                    <span id="showmenow" style="margin-left:-50px;"><a href="#"><h4>title</h4></a></span>
                                    <a href="#"><img ng-src="..." style="height: 30px; width: 90px"/></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar navbar-inverse" id="category_navbar" style="width:100%;position: fixed;">
                this is me
            </div>

            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Seems to work fine for me in this quick fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5hU7b/. Does the fiddle work for you?

Comment: It is working, But title is coming very slowly, after I've reached to the top. Scroll down three four times you will see. I want the title should start animate as soon as I reached to top.

Comment: Ah I see it now. Seems to happen when I scroll quickly. I'll have a proper look in a moment.

Comment: Did my answer help sort your problem? Let me know if I misunderstood at all.

Comment: If my answer did solve your problem. Would you mind marking it as accepted answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seemed to be 2 problems.

1. Your animate code is being called only once a `slideUp()` or `slideDown` animation had finished. Therefore best to take it outside the oncomplete function so that it will be called regardless of the previous animation having finished.
2. Your calling an animation on `$("#showmenow")` every time `$(window).scroll()` is called, even if it's not actually making any changes. The animation takes a certain amount of time even if it's not doing anything, and so a delay is being caused by waiting for the previous animations to finish. I think putting an if statement in to check whether the animation is required will sort this out.

So your JS code would become:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 160) {
            if($("#showmenow").css('marginLeft')=="-50px"){
                //only run when animation is required
                $("#showmenow").animate({'margin-left':"0px"});
            }
            $("#category_navbar").slideUp(function(){
                //only runs after slideUp() has completed
                $(".topextra").slideUp();
            });
        } else {
            if($("#showmenow").css('marginLeft')=="0px"){
                //only run when animation is required
                $("#showmenow").animate({'margin-left':"-50px"});
            }
            $(".topextra").slideDown(function(){
                //only runs after slideDown() has completed
                $("#category_navbar").fadeIn();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Here's a working JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5hU7b/1/

---

A slight alternative, instead of using if statements to check if the animation should run, you could instead use `stop()` (http://api.jquery.com/stop/) to stop previous animations and clear the queue. In which case your code would become:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 160) {
            //stop previous animations and clear queue
            $("#showmenow").stop(true).animate({'margin-left':"0px"});
            $("#category_navbar").slideUp(function(){
                //only runs after slideUp() has completed
                $(".topextra").slideUp();
            });
        } else {
            //stop previous animations and clear queue
            $("#showmenow").stop(true).animate({'margin-left':"-50px"});
            $(".topextra").slideDown(function(){
                //only runs after slideDown() has completed
                $("#category_navbar").fadeIn();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

And here's the JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5hU7b/2/

Comment: Using the stop() is perfectly working for me. Thanks.